# TableCell pangesture got ignore when inside a collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

**Question and situation explaination**

Hi I have a custom collection view that I make each collectionview cell the size of the screen and make it scroll horizontally so I get like a paging effect.

In each collectionview cell I have a tableview which also take up the whole size of that collectionview cell. I'm trying to implement trailing and leading swipe action of my tableview cell but it is being ignore because of the swipe gesture to scroll the collectionview cells.

Is there a way to maybe like set the collectionview cell to only watch for pangestures that are near the edge of the screen then scroll the collectionview, other wise the pan gesture will just be send to the tableview instead?

---

**Alternative solution (temporary work around)**

***Though I have found a work around but I still very much interested in finding out if what I'm trying to do above is possible so if you know please leave your answer***

So after searching and searching stackoverflow there seem to be other people with the same problem as mine but doesnt seem to be able to found an answer. Thus I have come up with another idea and I like to share so if anyone come across this problem they can have options to choose from.

My idea is adding a long press gesture regconizer for the tableview you can achieve that as follow in **swift 4**

```
func setupLongPressGesture() {
    let longPressGesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongPress))
    longPressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 // 1 second press
    longPressGesture.delegate = self
    dataDisplayTable.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGesture)
}

@objc func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
        let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: dataDisplayTable)
        if let indexPath = dataDisplayTable.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
            // let cell = dataDisplayTable.cellForRow(at: indexPath) - use this to retreive the cell at the above indexPath to do something with it
            // print(cell?.reuseIdentifier) - use this to retreive the cell identifier and do something with it
        }
    }
}
```

Then add this to your viewDidLoad()

```
setupLongPressGesture()
```

Comment: This seems like very bad UX.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri what is a bad UX? the paging effect with collectionview or I cant make it recognize pan gesture for both?

Comment: Having the swipe in the same direction as scroll seems like bad UX.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri hmmm you are right I have just come up with something that might be a better UX which is adding a long press gesture. Thank you the fact that you complaining about UX make me think harder about what i'm trying to do xD. Cheers. However I'm still interested to see if there is anyway I can make the swipe thingy work

Comment: Why not make it swipe up or down?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri swipe up or down is use for navigate through the tableview so that wouldnt be a great idea nor it is possible